# ufw blocking outgoing calls to whitelisted ip address

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw

So here is the scenario.

In my ubuntu, I want to block all outgoing traffic except to some IP addresses, which I do by adding ufw rules and it works fine. So the services I access from ubuntu is the MQTT client which listens on port 1884 on another server whose IP I have whitelisted in ufw. Now this works fine, until I try to establish a connection using secure MQTT on port 1885, now this doesn't work until I disable my firewall once, and when I re-enable it, it works every time. The point to note here is that the server IP address is whitelisted in ufw. So this doesn't make sense. If you have any ideas do let me know.

```
sudo ufw default allow incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out 53
sudo ufw allow out 60001
sudo ufw allow out ntp
sudo ufw allow out to xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

now this works until i use plain mqtt client with no tls, when i try to enable tls mqtt client this doesn;t work but works after i disable firewall, connect mqtt with tls and then re-enable the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With UFW the order of the rules matters. Looking at you list there you've got deny all outgoing set before the allow statement. So what will happen if when you try to make an outgoing connection UFW will check through the rules to see if there's a match and in this instance the first match it comes to is the deny all outgoing. So it blocks the connection, it doesn't check for any other matches.

If you edit the `user.rules` file in

```
/etc/ufw/user.rules
```

Then reorder the rules so you allow statement is before the deny all statement and it should work.

Comment: what if i do this
```
sudo ufw allow out 53
sudo ufw allow out 60001
sudo ufw allow out to xx.xx.xx.xx
sudo ufw allow out ntp
sudo ufw default allow incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

Comment: As the rules already exist in the firewall it'll just say skipping existing rule when you try to add them. If you Google it I think there are commands in ufw that can change the order but I'd say its far easier to just edit the file.